# Json parsing request fails to load table on MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a table containing user data that should be populated from a model using the E.F model. I have a json code but apparently it fails to fill the table when i use a custom Layout. However on using the default layout, it loads up fine.

I have tried getting rid of any scripts on the layout but none works

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var oTable = $("#myDataTable").DataTable({

            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Dashboard/GetAuditors",
                "type": "GET",
                "dataType": "json"
            },

            "columns": [

                { "data": "RegistrationNo", "autowidth": true },
                { "data": "AuditorName", "autowidth": true },
                { "data": "Organization", "autowidth": true },
                { "data": "EmailAddress", "autowidth": true },
                { "data": "PhoneNumber", "autowidth": true },

            ]
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Update: I just figured it out.    My  @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) wasn't placed at the body section

Comment: You could delete the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

$('#myDataTable').DataTable({
             "ajax": {
                "url": "/Dashboard/GetAuditors",
                "type": "GET",
                "dataType": "json"
            },

```
        "columns": [

            { "data": "RegistrationNo", "autowidth": true },
            { "data": "AuditorName", "autowidth": true },
            { "data": "Organization", "autowidth": true },
            { "data": "EmailAddress", "autowidth": true },
            { "data": "PhoneNumber", "autowidth": true },

        ]
    });
```